# Constraint Layout custom footer

Tags: java, android

I have a `custom footer` that is wrapped inside a constraint layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/CustomToolBarStyle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="startRecordStatsIntent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_stats"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="startProfileIntent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_profile"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the design spec, it looks pretty good as a stand alone component. [image]

However, when I try to include this footer in my other pages it looks like this:

[image]

Basically, the `ImageButtons` are all shifted to one side of the footer. Here is the code of the actual page and where I include the footer:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">



    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        layout="@layout/custom_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Not sure what is going on, any ideas?

Comment: Try removing `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"` from the second `ImageView` and see if it changes anything. It seems to be behaving as though there is no chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify your second xml file and it works fine. Just set width of `include2` to  `match_parent`

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           tools:context=".MainActivity"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_properties_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```